# mariadb-bin.index not found

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I cannot star mysql because the following error

```
Jun 20 13:11:08 c268743fb9f9 mysqld_safe[17699]: 170620 13:11:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.56-MariaDB-1~trusty) starting as process 17698 ...
Jun 20 13:11:08 c268743fb9f9 mysqld_safe[17699]: 170620 13:11:08 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
Jun 20 13:11:08 c268743fb9f9 mysqld_safe[17699]: 170620 13:11:08 [ERROR] Aborting
Jun 20 13:11:08 c268743fb9f9 mysqld_safe[17699]: 
Jun 20 13:11:08 c268743fb9f9 mysqld_safe[17699]: 170620 13:11:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

however, the file is there

```
root@c268743fb9f9:~# ls -la /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql adm 170 Mar 10  2015 /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
```

change permission, still the same. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions on the file look OK.  Other things to check:

- Did you start mysqld as root?
- Check for `-rwx......` on each directory leading down to that file.